# Convert RHEL Install into Bootable ISO

Tags: linux, rhel, iso

I have a Clonezilla-saved image of RHEL with some custom software installed and I need to make it into a bootable ISO for DVD.  One of the major problems I have is this version of RHEL was part of an offline development project and the enterprise registration isn't going to work, so I can only use CentOS repos if I need to install anything.  With this said, I have already restored the OS to a device and have mounted the lvm2 partitions.  I have booted into a live environment on Unraid.  (The live environment is Arch Linux) The partition structure is:

**/dev/vda1** (appears to be a normal `/boot`)

**/dev/vda2**

/dev/rhel/root

/dev/rhel/home

I have mounted all of these as follows:

> /dev/rhel/root ---> /mnt
>
> /dev/rhel/home ---> /mnt/home
>
> /dev/vda1      ---> /mnt/boot

What is the best way to make this into a read-only and bootable ISO?  Squashfs (on Arch) and Linux-Live Kit (again, on Arch) don't seem to work.

Comment: There is a package in debian called systemback where you can use it create live image from your OS and then convert the same live-image into iso. this iso would be bootable.

i did find this link incase if it helps for you
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2115051

Comment: Is this in a virtual machine?

Comment: The original is from a physical drive, however I am using the Clonezilla backup in a virtual.